# Тестирование @Formula

Tags: java, spring, юнит-тесты, mock

Всем доброго времени суток! Возникла проблема: поля помеченные @Formula во время MockMVC тестирования не срабатывают.
Если осуществлять проверку через Swagger, то работает все отлично, в тестах - иначе.

Метод контроллера (не обращайте внимания, если код с ошибками, главное - передана суть):

```
    @Override
public ResponseEntity<PersonRsDto> create(PersonRqDto personRqDto) {

    return Optional.ofNullable(personService.create(personRqDto))
            .map(created -> {
                created = personService.getById(created.getId());
                return ResponseEntity.body(created);
            })
            .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException(BAD_REQUEST_NO_CREATE));
}
```

Метод create:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public PersonRsDto create(@NonNull PersonRqDto personRqDto) {
    var src = personMapper.toEntity(personRqDto);
    var dst = personRepository.save(src);
    return personMapper.toDto(dst);
}
```

Сущность Person:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {

/**
 * Идентификатор
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

/**
 * Имя сотрудника
 */
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

/**
 * Фамилия сотрудника
 */
@Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
private String surname;

/**
 * Отчество сотрудника
 */
@Column(name = "middle_name")
private String middleName;

/**
 * Полное имя
 */
@Formula("CONCAT_WS( ' ', surname, name, middle_name ) ")
private String fullName;

/**
 * Краткое имя
 */
@Formula("CONCAT_WS( ' ', " +
        " surname, " +
        " CASE WHEN name IS NULL OR TRIM(name) = '' THEN NULL ELSE (UPPER(SUBSTRING(TRIM(name), 1, 1)) || '.' ) END, " +
        " CASE WHEN middle_name IS NULL OR TRIM(middle_name) = '' THEN NULL ELSE (UPPER(SUBSTRING(TRIM(middle_name), 1, 1)) || '.' ) END) ")
private String shortName;
```

}

Тест:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class PersonAPITest extends AbstractContainerizedTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    @DisplayName("Создание сотрудника")
    void createPerson() throws Exception {

        final var personName = "name";
        final var personSurname = "surname";

        final var personRqDto = PersonRqDto.builder()
                .name(personName)
                .surname(personSurname)
                .build();

        mockMvc.perform(postJson(personRqDto, COMMON_API_URI))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("personNumber", equalTo(personNumber)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("name", equalTo(personName)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("surname", equalTo(personSurname)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("fullName", equalTo("что-то"))); //NPE
    }
```

Comment: Что у вас в AbstractContainerizedTest? Главный вопрос, как у вас в тесте содзается сервис или personMapper. Я на 99% уверен, что вы мокаете или сервис или маппер при этом ясно что в БД запрос не идет. А `@Formula` работает именно при sql запросе БД. Так что, если вы замокали БД, то `@Formula` ожидаемо работать не будет. Как правильно проблему решить зависит от того, как вы создаете сервис и/или маппер. Главное, какую логику тестирует этот тест? Если он тестирует логику работы mvc, то не нужно в нем тестировать логику работы маппинга сущностей jpa.

Comment: Если же это типа тест уровня компонента, который работает через mockMvc, то нужно использовать реальную БД (можно inmemory) и не мокать с ней работу.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA доброго времени суток! Создается новый docker контейнер и в нем уже создается база данных. Если отслеживать (лог) работу hibernate, то при методе save открывается транзакция и происходит (я надеюсь) запись в базу данных. Но в методе getById транзакция открывается но запроса в БД не происходит(

Comment: Используется private MockMvc mockMvc;

Comment: Такое ощущение, что после метода save сущность сохраняется в кэше, а уже при вызове метода getById возвращается объект из кэша. Но тогда возникает вопрос: Почему работает через Swagger?

Comment: Если проблема в том, что в тесте запрос в БД не идет, то это и нужно в вопросе спрашивать :) Как у вас сконфигурирован personRepository?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136965/discussion-between-roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua-and-maxden).

Answer (score 0):

В общем и целом методы save и getById работали в рамках одной сессии и поэтому при вызове метода getById не осуществлялся запрос в БД, а информация (об объекте) бралась из кэша. Чтоб решить эту проблему нужно в properties указать:

```
open-in-view: false
```

Огромная благодарность пользователю: [Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218971/roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua)